Which cartoon episode has Green Lantern hitting Superman with a tennis racket and sending him flying?
I'm searching for the show and episode in which Green Lantern strikes Superman with a tennis racket, sending him flying off-screen. This clip appears at around 3:10 in a YouTube video titled "Batman Loses his Memory" by Solid jj.

The scene seems to be from an old cartoon, like many other clips in Solid jj's videos. Green Lantern's tennis racket is likely a construct created by his power ring. I'm curious about the context surrounding this unusual interaction between these two superheroes.
A Google Lens search of a screenshot from the scene only led me to a Tumblr post containing the clip, but without any additional details. Several search results mentioned the animated series Super Friends, suggesting this might be the source, but I couldn't find any specific episode information.
@Valorum found this GIF that seems to be from the same fight. In this scene, Green Lantern creates a mirror construct. When Superman uses his heat vision, it reflects off the mirror and hits him instead.

If this scene is indeed from Super Friends, does anyone know which episode it's from? And if not, can you identify the show and episode it's actually from?

https://64.media.tumblr.com/f255343b3df4cfa179108c51e0122d74/tumblr_n6rrrmXtHa1s2wio8o1_500.gifv

@Valorum Thanks. I added that GIF to my post.

Adding "Would a green mirror reflect red heat vision?" to the list of questions that I wonder about instead of getting to sleep at a reasonable time of night.

This is from the 1980 TV show Super Friends, it is from season 5 episode 5 "Voodoo Vampire - Invasion of the Gleeks - Mxyzptlk Strikes Again". The specific mini-episode you are looking for is "Mxyzptlk Strikes Again". You can watch the entire episode (and indeed the whole series) on the Internet Archive. The fight scene starts at around 20 minutes in.
In the episode Mxyzptlk uses a typewriter that plunges the Super Friends into alternate dimensions where they act out the "roles" that Mxyzptlk is writing for them. After being teleported to a "Wild-West Town" and forced to duel Aquaman, Superman is forced to fight Green Lantern, the "two most powerful Super Chumps", in order to decide who will be the star of Mxyzptlk's next novel.

The fight is very short, it's basically the whack with the tennis racquet from your first gif, the gag with the mirror happening after a minor back and forth, then Green Lantern traps Superman in his energy field, which just so happens to block the typewriter's effects, allowing them to save the day.

Found thanks to a very well timed Google Image reverse search that resulted in a link to this cbr 'Green Lantern Appreciation' thread, where the user "Güicho" kindly notes the episode title.

The link you mentioned doesn’t seem to lead to Güicho's post, but here's the correct one: https://community.cbr.com/threads/hal-jordan-green-lantern-appreciation-2020.133479/post-4939619. Funny how Mxyzptlk seems to favor Green Lantern—he takes down Superman twice here!
